# Banding results using Derivative Maps in Three.js

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping, derivative, normals

Is there a way around this issue? I've tried rendering out displacement at higher res but the banding issue seems to be prevalent. At first I had hard edges everywhere on the low poly which I got around by tessellating / smoothing the low poly prior to projection (of the displacement map from the high poly).

[image]

```
//// DERIVATIVE MAP
            var mapHeight = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "textures/horse_atlas_h.jpg" );

            mapHeight.anisotropy = 4;
            mapHeight.repeat.set( 0.998, 0.998 );
            mapHeight.offset.set( 0.001, 0.001 );
            mapHeight.wrapS = mapHeight.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            mapHeight.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

            materialHorse = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial

            ({
                map:                Horse_diffuseMap,
                //normalMap:        Horse_normalMap,
                //normalScale:      new THREE.Vector2( 2.4 , 2.4 ),
                metalness:          Horse_metalnessMap,
                roughness:          Horse_roughnessMap,
                bumpMap:            mapHeight,
                bumpScale:          10,
                alphaMap:           Horse_alphaMap,
                transparent:        true,
                skinning:           true
                // needsUpdate:     true
            });
```

Comment: You need to show your code and preferably provide a live working example to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I'm just using a standard material with a displacement map assigned in the bump slot. (edited above to show it)

Comment: Does your `bumpMap` contain values from 0 to 255, or is the range limited?

Comment: Picking colors in PS it looks like the range is 0 to 255. I've tried baking displacement from max, zbrush and xnormal. I can get 16bit maps out but the examples seem to be using 8bit jpgs.